# how to store measure value in table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have measure that store the Slicer selected value. now I want to store measure value in new table but not getting success. Please help here.

Also i want to know if there is a way to store slicer selected value in table directly.

below syntax i used to store slicer selected value in measure
Slicer_Value = selectedvalue(column)

Regards,
SK

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? What is the purpose to store this in an additional table? Try to explain what you want to achieve, provide samples.

Comment: sure, adding the same in question

Comment: It looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please give some context why do you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a slicer selection in one of your model tables (either in a new calculated table or a calculated column on an existing table) since these are only calculated when your data is loaded or refreshed rather than every time you make a slicer selection.

However, it's highly likely that there is another way to do whatever it is you are ultimately trying to achieve by another method.